# Doubly linked list. Trying to implement copy constructor from source into destination. Assuming destination's length is zero (C++)

Tags: c++, deque

```
 struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Node() : data(0), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) { }
    explicit Node(int elt) : data(elt), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) { }
};


class DequeEmptyException { };



class Deque {
 public:

Deque();

~Deque();


Deque(const Deque& orig);


Deque& operator=(const Deque& rhs);

 private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int length;

void copy(const Deque& source, Deque& destination);
};
```

here are is my copy constructor from source to destination.

```
 void Deque::copy(const Deque& source, Deque& destination) {
    // create dummy header
    destination.head = new Node;
    destination.head->next = destination.head->prev = destination.head;
    // copy nodes
    for (Node *p = source.head->next; p != source.head; p = p->next) {
    Node *t = new Node;
    t->data = p->data;

 // insert at end of list
    t->next = destination.head;
    t->prev = destination.head->prev;
    t->prev->next = t;
    t->next->prev = t;
    }
source.length = destination.length;
}
```

This is my attempt. Does it look correct as there are many other implementations within the Deque that I was unable to show. This was the most confusing.

Comment: `length` is an `int` so what are you really trying to do here: `length.destination = length.source;`? Shouldn't it be `destination.length = source.length;`?  Please put a [mre] in the question and explain what the problem is. Apart from the obvious error I noticed, what do you have troubles with?

Comment: yeah i added that last minute because i realized length had not been defined within the copy constructor

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66889649/edit) your question until it becomes clear what you need help with. As it now stands, I think it is in risk of being closed. Please read the link about making a [mre]

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, or printing things during execution? That for-loop looks wonky as well in `copy()`. Your title mentions "destination length is zero" -- what does that mean? When is your deque "empty"? When copying, what if the **source** is empty?

Comment: `// insert at end of list` -- If you have a function that already inserts at the end of the list *efficiently*, then you could simply just call that function in a loop, instead of having duplicate code.  Anyway, your `Deque` would be almost worthless if it didn't have such a function (how would the user be able to insert elements if that function didn't exist?).  Then the `for` loop simply becomes `for (Node *p = source.head->next; p != source.head; p = p->next) { destination.insert_at_end(p->data); }`

Comment: you are not implementing copy constructor correctly, if you provide a minimal reproducible example showing how you use the class, it would help US to help you!